# Assume that $A(X)$ is a unique factorization domain. Show that $\mathcal{O}_X (U) = A(X)$ if and only if $\operatorname{codim}Y \ge 2$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

> Let $Y$ be a non-empty irreducible subvariety of an affine variety $X$, and set $U = X \setminus Y$. Assume that $A(X)$ is a unique factorization domain. Show that $\mathcal{O}_X (U) = A(X)$ if and only if $\operatorname{codim}Y \ge 2$.

For the first implication assume that $\mathcal{O}_X (U) = A(X)$. That is the $\{ f : U \to k \mid f \text{ regular} \} = \dfrac{k[x_1, \dots, x_n]}{I(X)}.$

I'm now trying to argue by contradiction that $\operatorname{codim}Y \ge 2$, but I think I'm missing some theorems related to the codimension. Suppose first that $\operatorname{codim}Y = 0$, then I think this says that the supremum over all $n$ such that there is a chain $$Y \subset Y_0 \subsetneq Y_1 \dots \subsetneq Y_n \subset X$$ is $0$. That is $Y \subset Y_0 \subset X$. Now I'm not sure whether I need unique factorization for this implication, but I would be glad to hear some hints or theorems to help on proceeding with this.

Comment: For $\Rightarrow$: codimension $1$ primes in a UFD are principal, and $A \to A_f$ is never surjective for $f$ a non-unit. The converse is basically algebraic Hartog's lemma (since UFDs are normal)

Comment: I can't quite follow. Why do you look at the map related to localization? @math54321

Comment: Think about the definition of $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ when $U$ is the complement of $V(f)$

Comment: When $U$ is the complement of $V(f)$ it's a distinguished open set $D(f)$ and so $\mathcal{O}_X(D(f)) = A_f$, but I don't understand how this is relevant here as $Y$ is not of the form $V(f)$? @math54321

Comment: Please read my first comment again carefully. If $\operatorname{codim} Y = 1$, then since $A$ is a UFD ...

Comment: I haven't yet gotten to $\operatorname{codim} Y = 1$ as you see I'm stuck with the case $\operatorname{codim} Y = 0$ for now. @math54321

Comment: I didn't realize that you were stuck with the codim 0 case - my mistake. Anyways your understanding of codimension is incorrect - please review the definition of codimension in any textbook, and convince yourself that codimension 0 primes are the same as minimal primes, in any ring